# What does .start() function do in Python?

Tags: python

What does .start() do in the following script?

```
import re
str2 = re.search("\((\w+)\)", str1)
return str1[:str2.start()].strip()
```

Comment: Have you checked the relevant documentation?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.start

Comment: Try this in your interactive interpreter: `import re`, then `str1 = 'abc'`, then `str2 = re.search('b', str1)`, then `help(str2.start)`. If the inline help isn't sufficient, try `type(str2)`, and then you can search "Python SRE_Match start` in your browser. You do need to figure out whether you want Python 2.7 or Python 3.6 help (or, bizarrely, Python 2.0 help… but that usually doesn't happen), but that's all there is to it. This is how you (a) create a [mcve], and (b) find help on your own.

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please [mark it as 'accepted’](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Comment: I found this question pretty useful, especially because when one searches for 'what does .start() do in python' on Google, this is the first result, not the documentation. And the answer is way more concise and direct than the documentation. Code shaming is a real problem in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Python documentation for the start method

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

It returns the index of the substring that matched.

So, str2.start() is where the regex was matched in str1.
Think of that return as saying, 
Returning everything in str1 up to where the regex was matched, and strip whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

If you are more of a reader, the documentation of [`match.start()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.start) would tell you what it does.

If you are more of an experimenter, open an interactive `python` console, and input the following (feel free to change the input data, after all you are an experimenter):

```
>>> import re
>>> str1 = 'Hello (python) world'
>>> str2 = re.search("\((\w+)\)", str1)
>>> str2.start()
6
>>> str1[:6]
'Hello '
>>>
```

Short explanation: it tells you the index of the starting position of the match.

Hope this answer will teach you something more than just what does `match.start()` do ;-)